# Getting Version of an Assembly without loading it in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, assemblies, version

In a .NET Compact Framework 3.5 application I'm doing a version check in a fairly tight loop in order to know whether or not another assembly needs to be "upgraded" (have a new copy in another directory copied over it, then start it up again).

The problem is that `Assembly.LoadFrom(path).GetName().Version` locks the file and prevents said copying over.

[`AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname.aspx) would be a better way to get this (thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187999/how-do-i-get-the-version-of-an-assembly-without-loading-it)), as it doesn't permanently load the assembly into the AppDomain and thus doesn't lock the file, but it isn't available in the Compact Framework.

I could create a new `AppDomain`, but can't use the new domain's [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wcywcds.aspx) method as that's not supported in the Compact Framework.

As a last resort I thought I'd allow the assembly to actually be loaded with the `Assembly.Load(byte[])` overload, which would cause a massive memory "leak" in a tight loop since they're never unloaded.  To counter that I intended to first hash the assembly's byte array and check a cache of versions for a previous hit.  However, you guessed it, the byte array overload for [`Assembly.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) isn't supported in the Compact Framework.

I also considered adding AssemblyFileVersions, since they're easier to check anyway, but that's another thing in the growing heap of things not supported in the Compact Framework (my thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812966/getting-file-version-info-in-the-compact-framework) for not having to try this).

Please, tell me what I'm trying to do is possible so I stop hating this framework so much?

Comment: What did the native file version (in the answer at your last link) return?

Comment: Didn't try it, as you can't even set the File Version in the assembly.  The [attribute isn't supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute(v=VS.90).aspx).

Comment: I know that attribute isn't supported - I was curious if maybe the compiler simply set it to the AssemblyVersion during the build process (basically meaning that it's there, just not settable apart from the AssemblyVersion)

Comment: The [`FileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo(v=VS.90).aspx) class isn't in the Compact Framework, so if it does set it automatically there's still no way to check it.

Comment: The last link in your question points to a [SO question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812966/getting-file-version-info-in-the-compact-framework) where the answers points to a [blog article](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2010/09/28/GettingNativeFileInfoInTheCompactFramework.aspx) that shows how to query the native file version info

Comment: I did see that, but it's scary both in length and in raw memory access.  I was hoping I was missing something incredibly obvious. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to have to P/Invoke GetFileVersionInfo, GetFileVersionInfoSize, and VerQueryValue to get what your want.  The pinvoke.net site is a great tool for signatures and examples on such things.  They have GetFileVersionInfo prototyped, but not the others.  Let me know if you need help with them and I can probably get the signatures that will work.

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/GetFileVersionInfo.html

Also noticed the OpenNETCF library has this implemented in the OpenNETCF.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo class.  So you can download that library and see how they did it.

Comment: I seem to recall having gotten to the File Version somehow after receiving no response here and seeing that it was always 0.0.0.0.  However, I did not attempt either of the things you mention. We already use OpenNETCF in the project, so I'll definitely give at least that one a go and get back to you.  We've since worked around the problem, but I'm curious to see if it's possible.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Try the Product Version property.

Comment: Whoa, just noticed this was asked back in May.  Somehow it bubbled up to the top of my RSS reader.

Comment: I wondered how it got on somebody's radar ;)  Thanks for bumping it anyway, there are now some good answers I have to try when I get back on that project.

Answer (score 1):

there is [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil#Download) from the Mono project which does inspect assemblies without loading them. I think you can distribute and use to check the assemblyversion

Comment: Interesting prospect.  The project has [little to no official documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513319/mono-cecil-documentation-and-tutorials/1610581#1610581) so it might require groking the [source](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil).  I didn't see anything that jumped out as exposing the version information, but it might be in the `CustomAttributes` collection of the [AssemblyDefinition class](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyDefinition.cs).  I'll give it a try when time allows and report back.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: As far as distribution rights I don't see anywhere that explicitly says what license the project as a whole uses, but it appears that the individual source files contain the [MIT license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) verbiage. As long as it doesn't use code somewhere in it with a more restrictive license it should be fine to distribute.

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/trunk/lib/Gallio.3.2.750/licenses/Mono.Cecil.license.html this is what i found as licence, and this answer http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-cecil@googlegroups.com/msg01218.html

Answer (score 1):

you can retrieve this information using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) as Firo mentionned, here is a F# code snippet:

```fsharp
open Mono.Cecil

let getAssembly (filename: string) =
  AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(filename)

let getVersion (assembly: AssemblyDefinition) =
  let versionAttributeTypeName = typeof<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>.FullName
  match assembly.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(fun f ->f.AttributeType.FullName = versionAttributeTypeName) with
  | null -> None
  | a -> Some (a.ConstructorArguments.First().Value :?> string)

getAssembly @"path to assembly"
|> getVersion
```

the output from FSI

```
val getAssembly : filename:string -> AssemblyDefinition
val getVersion : assembly:AssemblyDefinition -> string option
val it : string option = Some "15.2.4.0"
```